# Python iterate a subprocess that returns json?

Tags: python, linux, json

I have a subprocess executing:

```
lshw -json -C network
```

If i receive the following back:

```
    {
    "id" : "network",
    "class" : "network",
    "claimed" : true,
    "handle" : "PCI:0000:00:05.0",
    "description" : "Ethernet interface",
    "product" : "82545EM Gigabit Ethernet Controller (Copper)",
    "vendor" : "Intel Corporation",
    "physid" : "5",
    "businfo" : "pci@0000:00:05.0",
    "logicalname" : "eth0",
    "version" : "00",
    "serial" : "00:8c:42:77:58:49",
    "units" : "bit/s",
    "size" : 1000000000,
    "capacity" : 1000000000,
    "width" : 32,
    "clock" : 66000000,
    "configuration" : {
      "autonegotiation" : "on",
      "broadcast" : "yes",
      "driver" : "e1000",
      "driverversion" : "7.3.21-k8-NAPI",
      "duplex" : "full",
      "firmware" : "N/A",
      "ip" : "10.211.55.10",
      "latency" : "0",
      "link" : "yes",
      "multicast" : "yes",
      "port" : "twisted pair",
      "speed" : "1Gbit/s"
    },
    "capabilities" : {
      "msi" : "Message Signalled Interrupts",
      "bus_master" : "bus mastering",
      "cap_list" : "PCI capabilities listing",
      "ethernet" : true,
      "physical" : "Physical interface",
      "logical" : "Logical interface",
      "tp" : "twisted pair",
      "10bt" : "10Mbit/s",
      "10bt-fd" : "10Mbit/s (full duplex)",
      "100bt" : "100Mbit/s",
      "100bt-fd" : "100Mbit/s (full duplex)",
      "1000bt-fd" : "1Gbit/s (full duplex)",
      "autonegotiation" : "Auto-negotiation"
    }
  },
```

Can i possibly iterate over this to ensure i capture all network interfaces (in the case that there's more than one) which is not the case with my system.. Also, how can i pick 1 or two from this output, i don't need the entire data.

I had the following in mind:

```
 def get_nic_data():
        lshw_cmd = "lshw -json -C network"
        proc = subprocess.Popen(lshw_cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                                      stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
        return proc.stdout


 def read_data(proc_output):
        import simplejason as json
        json_obj = json

        json_obj.loads(proc_output)

        #Obtain Vendor,Description,Product
        #...
        #...

        json_obj.dumps(obtained_data_here)

        #Not sure if this would work this way.


  read_data(get_nic_data())
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot combine `-C` class filtering with `-json` output; even in the latest version JSON output is severely broken. Instead, filter the *full* JSON output yourself. Note that you should avoid using `shell=True` when using `subprocess`, pass in a list instead; no need to pipe stdin either, but do capture (silence) stderr.

Then we can recurse over the 'children' structures, picking out anything that has a matching `'class'` key:

```
def get_nic_data():
    lshw_cmd = ['lshw', '-json']
    proc = subprocess.Popen(lshw_cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                      stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    return proc.communicate()[0]

def find_class(data, class_):
    for entry in data.get('children', []):
        if entry.get('class') == class_:
            yield entry

        for child in find_class(entry, class_):
            yield child

def read_data(proc_output, class_='network'):
    import json

    for entry in find_class(json.loads(proc_output), class_):
        yield entry['vendor'], entry['description'], entry['product']
```

then loop over `read_data(get_nic_data())`:

```
for vendor, description, product in read_data(get_nic_data()):
    print vendor, description, product
```

Comment: except `lshw -json` doesn't return a valid json text (at least on my machine).

Comment: `lshw -json` does not return a valid JSON in case of several results for same class, seems like it should be an array but `[` and `]` are missing

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: Bugger, I was hoping that was a mistake on the part of the OP. I didn't have a recent `lshw` release handy (it's all Debian Squeeze on my servers here). What is missing, the `[` and `]` brackets?

Comment: @Raber: Interesting, let's add those in.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: first there is a sequence of "\rsome text\r\r" then `{<valid json>} <many spaces> {<valid json>} ...`

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: But with commas after the `}` closing brackets it seems. Is `some text` perhaps dumped on stderr? The OP didn't include that in the question. Certainly the trailing comma needs to go (JavaScript, and by extension JSON is inflexible like that).

Comment: @MartijnPieters: there is no comma, just spaces.

Comment: It's amazing that this still isn't fixed, I'm finding tickets that talk about making this work as far back as 3 years ago! http://ezix.org/project/ticket/492 it looks like the JSON format code in lswh breaks when you limit your results with `-C` according to this: http://ezix.org/project/changeset/2138

Comment: @Jason and that was 3 years ago... sigh

Comment: @JasonSperske as you say, this breaks when using `-C` (using lshw B0.2.15)

Comment: @Dayan: I compiled the latest copy of lshw and found a work-around. Don't use `-C` and recursively search yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If there are multiple network cards `lshw` doesn't return a valid json text. It could be fixed by adding `[` / `]` before / after the output and adding `,` in between objects:

```
import json
import re
from subprocess import STDOUT, check_output as qx

# get command output
output = qx("lshw -json -C network".split(), stderr=STDOUT)

# get json parts
_, sep, json_parts = output.rpartition(b"\r")
if not sep: # no \r in the output
    json_parts = output

# convert it to valid json list
jbytes = b"[" + re.sub(b"}( *){", b"}, {", json_parts) + b"]"
L = json.loads(jbytes.decode())

# pretty print
import sys
json.dump(L, sys.stdout, indent=4)
```

A cleaner solution would use `lshw -xml` that produces output that could be easily converted to a well-formed xml by wrapping it in a root element: `'<root>'` + output + `'</root>'`.

Comment: @Dayan: I've tested it and it works on my machine. The solution is fragile against changes in the lshw output so drop `-C` option as @Martijn suggested to get a valid json.